# Отделить слова и числа при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: java

Добрый день.
Есть строка:

```
String str = "887i9qWerty1qwerty24";
```

Пытаюсь выделить сначала слова:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Потом числа:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Нельзя ли как то в одном выражении вычленить и слова и числа?

Comment: нет. то есть ты сможешь выдернуть и слова и текст, но отделить их на 2части в одной регулярке - нельзя

Comment: Могу такое сделать не с помощью регулярных выражений, а результат получить в двух ArrayList. (или как вам надо)

Comment: Денис, спасибо. Но я так сам могу :) Я думал как то хитро можно шаблон нарисовать, где отделяются числа и слова на их границе.

Comment: Ок, допустим есть какая то регулярка, которая делает то что вы хотите, вопрос, каким образом вы будете из нее получать поочередно то цифры то слова и как вы их друг от друга будете отличать?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а что, отличать буквы и цифры сложно?)) https://regex101.com/r/fK0tW1/1

Comment: Видимо нет, вы же написали регулярку будете поочередно получать то число то слово. В чем тогда проблема?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто получать слова и числа в одном потоке, не различая их, то можно использовать выражение `[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+`:

```
String str = "887i9qWerty1qwerty24";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Если же вам нужно их различать, то можно их выделять в разные группы, как-то так:

```
String str = "887i9qWerty1qwerty24";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)|([0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    String word = m.group(1);
    String number = m.group(2);

    if (word != null) {
        System.out.println("Word: " + word);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Number: " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Роман, отлично. Первый вариант, то что нужно! Благодарю!